# Почему результат функции на python отличен от результата на C++ и как исправить?

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x

Функция на Python:

```py
def inv(a, n): 
    if a == 0:
        return 0
    lm, hm = 1, 0
    low, high = a % n, n
    while low > 1:
        r = high//low
        nm, new = hm-lm*r, high-low*r
        lm, low, hm, high = nm, new, lm, low
    return lm % n
```

Функция на C++:

```cpp
int inv(int a, int n) {
    if (a == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    int lm = 1;
    int hm = 0;
    int low = a % n;
    int high = n;
    while (low > 1) {
        int r = high / low;
        int nm = hm - lm * r;
        int nw = high - low * r;
        lm = nm;
        low = nw;
        hm = lm;
        high = low;
    }
    return lm % n;
}
```

Python: `inv(198411, 524287)` -> 448444, C++: `inv(198411, 524287)` -> 0

Как исправить функцию на C++ что бы она работала как на Python?

Comment: Вы бы написали, что должна вычислять функция. Тогда было бы проще написать нормальный код, а не вот это вот все. Вы не понимаете, что это `lm = nm, low = nw, hm = lm, high = low;` — то же самое что `lm = low = high = nm`? Т.е. что все четыре переменные получают одно и то же значение?

Comment: Это для сокращения просто. Я уже эту функцию переделывал по всякому. Каждую переменную отдельно объявлял. И даже выносил из цикла. Результат один.

Comment: Сокращения это хорошо, но питоновское выражение `lm, low, hm, high = nm, new, lm, low` и плюсовое `lm = nm, low = nw, hm = lm, high = low` делают совершенно разные вещи.

Comment: Изменил для вас.

Comment: В том то и проблема, заставить этот код работать на плюсах.

Comment: Ну как только вы поймёте что же на самом деле делает код на питоне, так сразу сможете переписать на плюсы.

Comment: Инвертирование числа по модулю n. Вот только это знание не помогает.

Comment: Не код в целом, а конкретная строка. Вот https://diveintopython.org/ru/odbchelper_multiassign.html

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145791/discussion-between-alexey-ten-and-dr-robot).

Comment: Присваиваем разные значения сразу нескольким переменным:
a, b, c = 'Питон', 'C++', 'PHP'                                                                                                                   И x = y = z = 6 Всем трем переменным будет присвоено значение.                                                         Так что все тут верно. Не понятно о чем вы говорите.

Comment: @Dr.robot Алексей говорит о том, что эта строка на Питон и внешне схожий код на С++ делают разное.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запись `lm, low, hm, high = nm, new, lm, low` аналогична

```python
(lm, low, hm, high) = (nm, new, lm, low)
```

и она кортежу присваивает кортеж. Сначала создаётся один, а потом второй. Так как вы присваиваете последовательно в C++, не используя никаких дополнительных структур, то происходит ошибка логическая. Сначала вы присваиваете

```cpp
  lm = nm;
  // потом уже другое значение
  hm = lm;
```

и происходит эта ошибка. Чтобы её исправить, можно добавить запасные переменные с копиями этих значений.

```cpp
  int oldlm = lm ;
  lm = nm;
  int oldlow = low ;
  low = nw;
  hm = oldlm;
  high = oldlow;
```

Далее функция взятия остатка от деления немного отличается от C++ варианта при отрицательных переменных. В C++ она возвращает отрицательное число, а в Python - положительное. Это можно исправить, добавив делитель.

```cpp
  return ( lm + n ) % n;
```

В итоге получилось такое :

```cpp
int inv(int a, int n) {
    if (a == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    int lm = 1;
    int hm = 0;
    int low = (a + n) % n ;
    int high = n;
    while (low > 1) {
        int r = high / low;
        int nm = hm - lm * r;
        int nw = high - low * r;
        int oldlm = lm ;
        lm = nm;
        int oldlow = low ;
        low = nw;
        hm = oldlm;
        high = oldlow;
    }
    return ( lm + n ) % n ;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Очень информативный и хороший ответ.

Answer (score 2):

```
int inv(int a, int n)
{
    if (a < 1 or n < 2)
        return -1;
    int high = n, hm = 0, low = a, lm = 1;
    while (low)
    {
        int q = high / low;
        int u = high - q*low;
        int v = hm - q*lm;
        high = low;
        hm   = lm;
        low  = u;
        lm   = v;
    }
    return high == 1 ? (hm + n) % n : -1;
}
```

Comment: Этот вариант я уже видел.
Он работает, но этот вариант значительно отличается от кода на python.
Если вам не сложно, можете дать пояснение, почему так должно работать?
Я не хочу получать -1. Я хочу ноль. Этот ответ не раскрывает проблему.
Дайте пожалуйста комментарий как это работает, для того что бы пометить ответ как решённый спасибо.

Comment: Замените `return -1` на `return 0`. Что до описания, как работает — как только вы поясните, как работает код на python, чтобы это не смахивало на "сыграю лоха в темную, а то от меня кроме реализации на С++ требуют еще и объяснение работы алгоритма, авось прокатит..."

Comment: Я плохо знаю python. Но нужно эту функцию перевести на плюсы. Ваша реакция очень бурная. Зачем вы тут?
Если вы подозреваете что вас используют, и от вас что-то требуют, не отвечайте на вопрос. 
Я пишу на C++ и мне потребовалась помощь перевода с python и все. А от вас одни упреки и минусы.
Продолжайте улучшать комьюнити.

Comment: Знаете, если бы вы, как масса других, просто привели код на питоне и "помогите перевести" — я бы просто проголосовал за закрытие вопроса. Вы привели код и на С++, я его переделал. Код делает то, что вам надо. Что я получаю? Что я не так сделал вашу домашку :) Знаете, как-то смешно после этого предъявлять еще какие-то претензии...